# Finder tags not showing thumbnail previews on external hard drive

Tags: finder, hard-drive, preview, finder-tag

I am on Mojave 10.14.6.  I am trying to use tags to filter my many many images on my external hard drive.

My thumbnail previews look like this when I click on the tag.  I have tried just about everything. Deleting the plst. file, relaunching finder. Everything.

[image: example of tags not showing the preview]

However, if I tag something on the main drive Or not in any folder on the external drive, It will show the thumbnail. I am using a toshiba 4TB external hard drive.

[image: example of thumbnails showing on the external not in a folder of any kind]